# Show demo code for React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, markdown, demo

I would like to make a demo page for my React component.

And I want to make it like http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button, which has:

1. some description of `props`. I would like to use `markdown`
2. demo of component
3. the code that shown demo section

Currently, I have a file like this (`Typescript`)

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class SimpleExamples extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>): void {
        // Do something here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p><code>MyComponent </code> is bla bla bla with <code>value</code> prop and <code>onChange</code> prop.</p>
                <p> You can make it like this or like that ... etc </p>
                <MyComponent value={this.state.value} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event) } />
                <br />

                <div style={{ marginTop: 12, marginBottom: 12 }}>
                    <CodeExample />
                </div>;
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It looks messy, and `CodeExample` shows the whole file which is I don't want.

I want it to show just the demo like this:

```
<MyComponent value={this.state.value} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event) } />
```

I thought about split the demo to a seperate file. But then, there will be a lot of them.

Any idea to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've was looking for a solution for this all over and Docusaurus was the best available option I found.

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternatives. You can roll your own demo if you build the component with [nwb](https://github.com/insin/nwb) namely this feature [here](https://github.com/insin/nwb#react-components-and-libraries).

You can build your component and demo in the same project and deploy them seperately and host it on the projects [github pages](https://pages.github.com/)

But NWB does not provide Markdown support out of the box for the demo.
If you want to do something a little bit more elaborate you can use [docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) (recently released by facebook) or even [storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook) (no markdown though)

**Docusaurus**

- Powered by Markdown

> Save time and focus on your project's documentation. Simply write docs
>   and blog posts with Markdown and Docusaurus will publish a set of
>   static html files ready to serve.

- Built Using React

> Extend or customize your project's layout by reusing React. Docusaurus
>   can be extended while reusing the same header and footer.

- Ready for Translations
- Document versioning
- Document search

Personally I've used NWB and Docusaurus and I think I'll stick with Docusaurus for now. But I think it really depends on what you want to do with the demo. If you have a ton of functional features to show than I'd recommend **storybook**, if it's mainly API based **NWB/Docusaurus**